# Why I am getting this NameError while running my class program?

Tags: python, oop

```
class Animal: 

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

    def sound(self):
        return 'this is animal sound'

    class Dog(Animal):
        def __init__(self,name, breed):
            super().__init__(name)
            self.breed=breed

    class Cat(Animal):
        def __init__(self,name,breed):
            super().__init__(name)
            self.breed=breed

doggy=Dog('Tomy','pug')
print(doggy.sound())
```

And it showed the following error:

```
----------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exception_handlin_2.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Animal:
  File "exception_handlin_2.py", line 9, in Animal
    class Dog(Animal):
NameError: name 'Animal' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you ensure the indentation is correct? As written it looks like `Cat` and `Dog` are nested within the `Animal` class?

Comment: There shouldn't be any spaced between `class Dog` and the start of the line. And the same goes for `class Cat`

Comment: Thank you so much. I have corrected indentation. Its running correctly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation. The class definition of `Dog` and `Cat` should be 1 indentation lower.

```
class Animal: 

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

    def sound(self):
        return 'this is animal sound'

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self,name, breed):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.breed=breed

class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self,name,breed):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.breed=breed

doggy=Dog('Tomy','pug')
print(doggy.sound())
```